# Why does a proof by contradiction mean that $r<b$ in the division algorithm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So we start off with the division algorithm which is known as $a = qb + r$ or also $r = a - bq$ when needed. We have already established that the set S is non-empty and that $r\in S$. (ps. the set is formatted like this $S=\{ r\in \mathbb{N}| r=a-bx, x\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ Now we have to prove that $r < b$. The way that my book does it is this:

We assume the opposite $$r  \geq b.$$ This means that $r - b \geq 0$

so

$$0  \leq r-b=(a-bq)-b=a-b(q+1)$$

Since $$a-b(q+1)$$ is non negative it is an element of our set by definition. But since b is positive it is true that $$r-b<r$$

Thus,

$$r-b=(a-bq)-b=a-b(q+1) < r$$

But r was to be the least element of set S and the equation above seems to say that there is another element of S smaller than r. Therefore r < b

How come this contradiction proves that $r < b$? We made two assumptions in the beginning. One was that R is the least element and the other was that $r > b$. Couldn't this contradiction prove either of them? In addition, from what I can see all we have proved is that $r$ is not the least element in the set $\mathbb{S}$, not that $r < b$. All help would be appreciated in answering this question as I have tried for a while to understand.

Comment: The variable $r$ is being used to denote the smallest possible element in a set.  There are two possibilities:  either $r \geq b$ or $r < b$.  The first possibility, that $r \geq b$, leads to a contradiction.  Therefore, it is impossible that the least element, $r$, is $\geq b$.  Therefore, the least element, $r$, must be $< b$.

Comment: @user2661923 I don't quite understand how the contradiction disproves that r >= b. It just says that there is an element in Set S that is less than r. Doesn't this just prove that r is not the least element?

Comment: Good question, but no.  The variable $r$ has been arbitrarily designated as the least element of the set.  Such a *least element* must exist.  So, the fact that $r$ is the least element becomes a **fixed** premise, that in and of itself does not contradict anything.  Since the assumption that $r \geq b$ leads to a contradiction, and since the fixed premise that $r$ is the least element is itself a non-contradictory premise, the contradiction has been **caused** by the assumption that $r \geq b$.  So, whatever is the value of the *least element of the set*, this value can not be $\geq b.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was written in the book's proof was:

$$ S = \{ a - nb \mid \text{$n \in \mathbb Z$ and $a - nb \geq 0$}\}. $$

Note no use of the symbol $r$ yet.

They then prove that the set is non-empty.

They then invoke the well-ordering principle, which proves that $S$ has a least element.

They then **give a name** to the least element (already proved to exist). They call it $r.$

So far, nothing has been assumed (other than the given conditions of the theorem, of course), only proved.

They then assume that $r \geq b.$ This indeed **is** an assumption that was not part of the conditions of the theorem. It is also the first and only such assumption that is made.
So when we arrive later at a contradiction, it specifically contradicts this assumption.

Comment: +1 : Thanks for the bail-out.  Nicely written.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I thought more about this just to make sure I am not asking a completely dumb question. How does proving that the arbitrary value r is less than b, prove that the actual remainder in the division algorithm is less than b?

Comment: Because $r$ is **not an arbitrary value.** It is the very-well-defined smallest value of the very-well-defined set $S.$ Once you have chosen $a$ and $b,$ the value of $r$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: Once we know that there is a least element, we simply call it r, right? I am unsure of how by calling this least element r (without knowing if the remainder in the algorithm is the least element) we are able to use it for the contradiction. In other words, we call the least element, r, but we don't know if the r from the equation is actually the least element.

Comment: What is "the equation"? I see no use of $r$ in any equation in the proof until after it has been named. Then the proof asserts that $r = a - qb$ for some integer $q$, which we know to be true because $r \in S.$ That is, this equation comes *from the definition* of $r$, not the other way around. It would help if you copied the proof out word for word instead of writing your own interpretation of it in the question, because indeed your interpretation is poorly sequenced and doesn't entirely make sense.

Comment: (Reference [the original proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlGbs.png), linked [to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4429866/139123).)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I realized that we definitively know that r is the least element by default because otherwise, it would not be the remainder. I found that this website explained it well (just for future reference for people who search for this question) http://mathcenter.oxford.emory.edu/site/math125/proofDivAlgorithm/